# Adobe Muse and Google Analytics

Tags: html, css, muse

I'm helping out our Marketing Director with a site he's making in Adobe Muse.  And he wanted me to set up Google Analytics, which I did.  Then he asked me (since we have a Desktop and a Mobile site) if we should put the Google Analytics script on the mobile and desktop page.

How does Adobe Muse work?  Does it just do media queries for device size?  If so, just putting the script in any page should work, because it's the same HTML code?  Or, in both?  I have no experience in this.

Comment: Hi Thomas, this question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. Questions here should be specific, and, ideally, about code/problems with code. I'd recommend checking out a site like https://helpx.adobe.com/muse/how-to/what-is-muse.html for answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Google Analytics to track visits to the mobile pages, then you need to be sure the tracking code gets on them.  This is typically done by adding the code to the mobile master in addition to that which you have presumably added to the desktop master.  The mobile home page is distinct from the desktop home page, and any analytic code on the desktop home page will do nothing when the mobile home page is visited.  The pages are completely distinct and separate.

I suggest you ask your "how does Muse work" question separately as it has nothing to do with the question title.  It will behove you to make it more specific.